# create object from imported model in A-frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I imported a house model as .gltf. From this house, I would like to retrieve the floor object and convert it into its own a-frame entity so that I can reference it later. I need to reference it in order to tell the [aframe-teleport-controls](https://github.com/fernandojsg/aframe-teleport-controls) component that it should use the floor as *collisionEntity*.

This is what I have so far:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('floor-test', {
    schema: {
        floorname: {type: 'string', default: "floor"},
    },
    init: function () {
        this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", (e) => {
            let child = this.el.object3D.getObjectByName(this.data.floorname, true);

            let floor = document.createElement("a-entity");
            floor.setObject3D("Object3D", child)
            floor.setAttribute("id", "floor")
            this.el.appendChild(floor)
        })
    }
});
```

This is the aframe-teleport-controls entity:

```
<a-mixin id="teleport" teleport-controls="type: parabolic; cameraRig: #cameraRig; collisionEntities: #floor "></a-mixin>
```

The object is being created (Not yet in the right position), but the teleport controls don't recognize it as a collision entity.

**How can I set the floor from the 3D model as collision entity?**

**EDIT**

Chaning `floor.setObject3D("Object3D", child)` to `floor.setObject3D("mesh", child)` fixed the problem of the teleport collision entitys.

But the floor object that is being created does not have the right rotation.

I tried the function `entityEl.object3D.getWorldRotation();` in the [a-frame docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/developing-with-threejs.html#local-to-world-transforms), but it returns "0 0 0"instead of "0 180 0".

I also tried to use `THREE.SceneUtils.detach(child, parent, scene);` but the child object didn't show up in the scene.

Here is the current code

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('floor-test', {
    schema: {
        floorname: {type: 'string', default: "floor"},
    },
    init: function () {
        this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", (e)=> {
            let parent = this.el.object3D;
            let child = parent.getObjectByName(this.data.floorname, true);

            let floor = document.createElement("a-entity");
            floor.setObject3D("mesh", child)
            floor.setAttribute("id", "floor")
            floor.setAttribute("rotation", child.getWorldRotation())

            this.el.appendChild(floor)
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: There may be other issues here, but it's standard to use `setObject3D('mesh', thing)` instead of the name `Object3D`. [teleport-controls expects this.](https://github.com/fernandojsg/aframe-teleport-controls/blob/master/index.js#L324-L326)

Comment: Thank you @DonMcCurdy, this solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an issue with the timing. When the `teleport-controls` are attached to the `teleport` mixin, the `#floor` is non-existent. Since i don't see any 'refresh' method in the [documentation](https://github.com/fernandojsg/aframe-teleport-controls), I can think of two ways of dealing with this:

1) If the world is non-procedural, add an invisible box where the floor should be and make it Your `#floor`.

2) a bit more legit, try adding the `teleport-controls` when the model is done loading:

```
this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", (e) => {
        let child = this.el.object3D.getObjectByName(this.data.floorname, true);

        let floor = document.createElement("a-entity");
        floor.setObject3D("Object3D", child)
        floor.setAttribute("id", "floor")
        this.el.appendChild(floor)
        let teleportEntity = document.querySelector("#teleport");
        teleportEntity.setAtrribute("type", "parabolic");
        teleportEntity.setAttribute("cameraRig", "#cameraRig");
        teleportEntity.setAttribute("collisionEntities", "#floor");
    })
```

```
<a-mixin id="teleport"></a-mixin>
```

Comment: I implemented the 2nd one and created the controls after the model has loaded, but it still did not work. After some testing, I found that the teleport controls are somehow not even working with a simple plane ([Here is the Glitch Project](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/even-hill?path=index.html:1:0)). Do you think there is something wrong with my teleport controls setup @Piotr Adam Milewski?

Comment: @JesterWest the mixins should be used a bit [differently](https://jsfiddle.net/dkmt4zw0/) <- check out the fiddle. `<a-mixin>` should be in the assets, then you put the `mixin` in a `<a-entity>`. Try following the [teleport controls example](https://github.com/fernandojsg/aframe-teleport-controls#usage), and put the teleport controls in at least one hand ( one for laser controls, one for teleport controls, just brainless copypaste to see if it works)